# EXIF Image data and Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, exif, windows-explorer

I have a problem with EXIF image properties and Windows Explorer

I've done a fair bit of trawling google for an answer on this but to no avail. I have written some C# code to get/set EXIF properties for images and the code works fine. For example, I can get the title property, update it and subsequently re-retrieve the new value.

However, although this all works fine, when I check the the properties of the image in Windows Explorer the details tab still shows the original subject.

This is how my code looks for the properties:

```
/// <summary>
/// Subject Property
/// </summary>
public string Subject
{
  get { return UnicodeToString((byte[])m_MetaData.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=" + Convert.ToInt32(ExifFields.Subject) + "}")); }
  set { m_MetaData.SetQuery("/app1/ifd/exif:{uint=" + Convert.ToInt32(ExifFields.Subject) + "}", StringToUnicode(value)); }
}
```

And:

```
  public enum ExifFields
  {
    ...
    Subject = 0x9c9f
    ...
  }
```

Any ideas anyone? (if it helps I can post the full class)

PS - this is my first SO post, so be gentle!

EDIT:

I've noticed some other behaviour that might help. If I use my code to set the exif values on an image with no exif values already, then everything works just fine. When I have an image with pre-existing values that get modified, the value 'appears' to be changed (i.e. when I read the values back in code they have changed) but WE displays the old values still. So my problem is with updating the properties and not 'creating' them.

Comment: No idea what tag 40095 might be.  Use an exif reference: http://www.cipa.jp/english/hyoujunka/kikaku/pdf/DC-008-2010_E.pdf

Comment: 0x9c9f (40095) is - Exif.Image.XPSubject as defined at [http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html](http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html) I think these were added for Windows. The reference is useful though as it explains the structure of the file.

Comment: So as not to muddy the water, the problem also occurs when writing the description (0x10e).

Comment: have you tried to clean windows thumbnail cache?

Comment: @Thaven - Yes, just tried cleaning the Thumb cache but to no avail.